# Finding the location from phone serivce provider

Tags: iphone, android, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make an application in iPhone and Android so that I can get the location of the user through the service provider of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Android : Use the [LocationProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html)'s requestLocationUpdates method. To get the location from service provider use the NETWORK_PROVIDER as the provider string.